# Drawing a Grid of Dots on a PictureBox in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, picturebox

I have been searching for about 12 hours now trying to find a way to draw dots on a PictureBox, I've found many threads giving example code and yet I just can't seem to get done what I want.

In essance what I am trying to do is this:

I have a windows form with a PictureBox on it, I do not have any Image in the PictureBox, however I do have the BackColor set to Black. I am trying to create a new bitmap image then run code to create white dots in the following style:

```
    ..........
    ..........
    ..........
    ..........
```

Thus giving me a grid style Look on the PictureBox.  However at every attempt I have failed, so if anyone could help me understand how to work with this I would appreciate it.

My most recent attempt was to use the ControlPaint.DrawGrid Method, like so:

```
private void picBox_Display_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Size size = new Size(35, 35);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0,0,picBox_Display.Width, picBox_Display.Height);
    ControlPaint.DrawGrid(Graphics.FromHwnd(picBox_Display.Handle), rect, size, Color.White);
}
```

The above code is in the PictureBox Paint event method.  I know it runs through the code because I have a breakpoint at the end of the method, but nothing happens.  I'm not sure I understand how the ControlPaint.DrawGrid works am I supposed to be adding something else?

I tried using the Bitmap.SetPixel method earlier today but kept having issues with it and kept looking for other ways to try to get it done.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to just draw dots to the screen, or actually have the dots drawn to a bitmap? ie is the bitmap only there to achieve the drawing of the dots?

Comment: The End Result is I want to draw dots to a bitmap image and then assign it to the pictureBox.Image, but ive had problems doing that too then I saw the ControlPaint.DrawGrid method and thought id try it. but i still had problems, however after running the exe program without debugging i could see the dots, but like i said Im still trying to find a way to get the dots onto an image and im thinking i was having the same problems with the vs debugger so im going back to try the SetPixel method, unfortunately i already deleted that previous code so ill have to work on it some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use e.Graphics for this. Note also that debugging this sort of code can be difficult because debugging often invalidates the drawing so it needs to be drawn again. The last parameter is meant to be the background color against what you are painting, so it looks like it draws the opposite of what you specify. If you background is black you need to pass in Color.Black

```
ControlPaint.DrawGrid(e.Graphics, rect, size, Color.Black);
```

Comment: Thank you apparently you got it on all 3 accounts, I am really surprised about the debugging issue, that may have been my largest issue, I always use the Debug feature of VS.  With this I guess ill have to make sure its working using the exe the build function creates, thanks for your help...

Comment: @MarkSweetman Debugging is fine it's just that if you breakpoint inside the paint event then that often brings up visual studio over the top of your app. This means that your app is no longer "painted" so when you run it needs to paint again which causes it to break again etc.